# Flutter use "listview" to list nearest location marks

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, location

I'm trying to use listview to list nearest "barber" locations on my Firebase. I can get location from the user but unable to find a documentation for this. I'm using Flutter and Dart.

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) and [enter link description here](http://geoflutterfire2) are very easy to use.